# Proper way to update pixel array data

Tags: opengl, c++, textures

For a game that updates a board every frame I am calculating the next arrangement of board, updating pixel array data and render board as 2D texture to quad the size of the screen using OpenGL. 
I use:

```
glTexImage2d(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,tex_width,tex_height,0,GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, &pixel_data.front())
```

to initialize the texture object and

```
glTexSubImage2d(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,tex_width,tex_height, BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, &pixel_data.front())
```

to update the texture.

The slowest part of the code is `update_pixels()` (below) Taking  256x128 elements input array and creating four component pixel array based on that. This function is very slow(45ms) and it seems it should be done differently. What would be the proper way to implement this function?

Update pixel data per frame:

```
void  update_pixels() {
//update pixels
//std::vector <unsigned char> pixel_data
float state = 0;
size_t it = 0;

for (size_t y = 0; y < board.getWorldHeight(); ++y) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < board.getWorldWidth(); ++x) {
        state = board.get_state(y * golf_board.getWorldWidth() + x);

        pixel_data[y * board.getWorldWidth() + x + it ] = static_cast<unsigned char>(state * 255);
        ++it;
        pixel_data[y * board.getWorldWidth() + x + it] = static_cast<unsigned char>(state * 255);
        ++it;
        pixel_data[y * board.getWorldWidth() + x + it] = static_cast<unsigned char>(state * 255);
        ++it;
        pixel_data[y * board.getWorldWidth() + x + it] = static_cast<unsigned char>(1 * 255);

    }

}
return;
}
```

Time measurement:

```
void render(){
render_frame() //glDrawElements() for quad and scale uniform update takes 0.2ms
generate_states() //new states for board takes 1.3ms
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
update_pixels(); // create new pixel array, takes 32 ms
auto t2 - std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
float update_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count() /1000.0f;
//cout <<updae_time
glfwSwapBuffers() //from update pixels to swap takes 13ms
}
```

Comment: Should `it` be set to zero in the loop body?

Comment: Or `y * board.getWorldWidth() + x` removed from the subscript of `pixel_data`?

Comment: You could also calculate things once, store them, and use them multiple times to improve performance just a tad.

Comment: If `board.get_state` is just indexing an array then you could use a single loop rather than a nested loop

Comment: If the pixel data vector is initialized in the scope of the update pixels function then you'd be allocating and deallocating memory every function call.

Comment: @Kerndog73 vector is initialized outside the scope of update function. Still i could not understand the suggestion to calculate things only once. The board will be updated every frame and each element state gives value to one pixel color. it will be either black or white since there are two possible states for one element on the board. 
And does nested for loop affect performance in significant way?

Comment: `y * board.getWorldWidth() + x` is calculated 5 times in the loop body when it only needs to be calculated once. `board.getWorldWidth()` is called 196608 times in the whole function but only needs to be called once. `board.getWorldHeight()` is called 128 times when it only needs to be called once. That's what I mean by "calculate things once and use them multiple times"

Comment: If the texture is just black and white then you don't need a color texture. You could use a gray scale texture.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this function is running for 45ms. Are you certain that **this** function is taking all that time and not something else?

Comment: If you'd store `state` in the texture's format directly (i.e. as `unsigned char`, multiplied by 255) you could upload that array as-is, as an RED channel and do the correct handling/interpreting of that data in your shader.

Comment: @Kerndog73 I added time measurement code above. Is it possible that if given the function update_pixel something else can take that time. Also making the fixes  and not calling get functions so often made function faster. before it took 37 now it takes 32 milliseconds.

Comment: @tkausl Following your advice i completely removed update pixel function. This made it possible to render 1024x512 board  with about 22ms aframe so faster that 16x smaller board with previous update function. So only the update board function now takes time and becomes bottleneck. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to speed up would be to use the smallest texture format for the job.

Since your `Alpha` is always 1 and all three components `RGB` are the same value you should use `GL_RED` (OpenGL 3.0 and later) or `GL_LUMINANCE` (up to OpenGL 3.0).

This creates a single-component texture so you do not need to copy the value 3 times and add a constant alpha value of 1.0 (255).

Up to OpenGL 3.0:

```
glTexImage2d(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, tex_width,tex_height, 0,GL_LUMINANCE,　GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel_data.data());
```

or OpenGL 3.0 onward:

```
glTexImage2d(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, tex_width,tex_height, 0, GL_RED,　GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel_data.data());

const GLint swizzleMask[] = {GL_RED, GL_RED, GL_RED, GL_ONE};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

This makes your texture a series of single bytes, one per pixel. Reducing CPU memory bandwidth, CPU<->GPU bus transfer, and GPU memory bandwidth requirements.

The texture is returned by the sampler as `{RED, RED, RED, 1}` or `{LUMINANCE, LUMINANCE, LUMINANCE, 1}` (same thing, older OpenGL).

This way only 1 byte per pixel need to be written.

Also reduce the two loops to a single continuous loop of width*height and avoid calculating the loop limit on every iteration:

```
//GLubyte *pixels = &pixel_data.front();
GLubyte *pixels = pixel_data.data(); // C++11

for (size_t i=0, count=board.getWorldHeight()*board.getWorldWidth(); count--; ) {
    *pixels++ = static_cast<GLubyte>(board.get_state(i++) * 255);
}
```

The post-decrement/post-increment operators helps modern CPUs do out-of-order execution.

To speed things up further you should also consider storing your board state as fixed points or a copy of it as a bytes to avoid the costly float to integer conversion multiple times every redraw.

If you maintain a copy of the state as bytes whenever modifying your states you can directly update the texture when something change.

And look into avoiding updating the texture when no state have effectively changed if this is a frequent occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed it up would be to access the arrays directly rather than doing a monstrous number of indexed look-ups into them when you're accessing the sequentially. It could look something like this:

```
unsigned char* nextPixel = &pixel_data [ 0 ];
const int boardHeight = board.getWorldHeight();
const int boardWidth = board.getWorldWidth();
const int numPixels = boardHeight * boardWidth;
for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; ++i)
{
    const float state = board.get_state(i);
    const unsigned char channel = static_cast<unsigned char>(state * 255.0);

    // red
    *nextPixel = channel;
    nextPixel++;

    // green
    *nextPixel = channel;
    nextPixel++;

    // blue
    *nextPixel = channel;
    nextPixel++;

    // alpha
    *nextPixel = 255;
    nextPixel++;
}
```

I also recommend using the appropriate types for your data. An OpenGL texture is not a series of individual `unsigned char`s. It's a 2 dimensional array of RGBA pixels. You should make a structure for them:

```
struct RGBAPixel {
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha;
};
```

Then your code wouldn't need the comments I added. But this isn't [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), so I'll stop here.

Comment: Using these fixes save 5 ms given the same amount of input data.  Still slow for larger boards.

Comment: It occurs to me that my code is *still* repeating stuff unnecessarily. You could calculate `static_cast<unsigned char>(state * 255)` once per loop. I'll update that. The other thing you could do is instead of calling `board.get_state(i)` every iteration, also get the start of the state array and run through it just like with the pixel array. I don't know if you have a method that gives you that address, though.

Comment: Oh, and as mentioned in the comments to the original question, you could use a single channel image with no alpha channel. That would reduce your workload in the loop by 75%.

Comment: yes, see the comment by tkausl to first question. the whole update_pixels() function can be avoided, just a little tweak is needed in shader to represent color accurately.